# On the linerarlayout draw textview and edittext

Tags: android, xml

hy, i have got problem with my code :)

First picture at the moment i write but i want second, what i must change
[image: Firs picture at the moment i write but i want second, what i must change]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView android:id="@+id/cautiontext"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="W:" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="0"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/cautiontext" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Height" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_row="1" android:layout_column="0"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="103dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_row="1" android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Problem is because i want to draw textview and edittext horizontal not vertical. I dont know what i must change.

Comment: orientation horizontal for linear layout

Comment: change linearlayout orientation to horizontal

Comment: Remove `android:orientation="vertical"` from LinearLayout. Adding `android:orientation="horizontal"` is not required as the LinearLayout, by default, has the horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout, the orientation is Vertical.  This means that views added to the layout will be added "vertically" or one of top of the other.  To get the effect you want, switch to "horizontal" so that the views are "beside" each other.

Answer (score 2):

Change the Orientation from Vertical to Horizontal for the linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Answer (score 2):

Only change android:orientation="vertical" to

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your LinearLayout orientation to horizontal, and that should work for you.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```